# Measure deletes itself after linking table

Tags: excel, ssis, ms-office, powerbi, microsoft-dynamics

I have three tables that I created on Excel as sample data:

1. **Products**

   - Code
   - Product
   - Price
2. **Vendors**

   - Employee Number
   - Name
   - Store number
3. **Sales**

   - Product
   - Quantity
   - Vendor
   - Operation type
   - Date

When the information gets imported into Power BI Desktop some relationships are made automatically by default but other don't.

For example, some information are automatically marked or parsed as measures, like **Sales.Quantity** or **Product.Price**.

But when I link **Product.Code** with **Sales.Product** the measure **Price** disappears, it looks and works only like whole or fixed number but it does not SUM or Count the column,

What am I doing wrong?